# React native is not running on physical device (Q mobile) while running on other physical devices

Tags: react-native

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN1EW.jpg) I tried cli and "react-native run-android deviceId" but it didn't work and facing same error . Cell phone (Q mobile LT700)

> ERROR

```
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
> details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
> connected and have set up your Android development environment:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
> > 
> > 
> >
```

Comment: you can't run react-native on connected device more than one, run `adb devices` and make sure the connected device showing one list

Comment: as the error said `read the error above` so could you please paste the complete error you got ??